# installing open query graph on MariaDB Galera server

Tags: mariadb, galera, oqgraph

I have problem with installing oqgraph engine, can anyone suggest something??

> " ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'ha_oqgraph.so' (errno: 8, API version for STORAGE ENGINE plugin OQGRAPH not supported by this version of the server) ".

my installation steps on centos 6.8 minimal are following:

**1-** Setting up MariaDB Repositories
**2-** install epel-release and socat
**3-** install Development Tools
**4-** install wget
**5-** install boost boost-devel boost-doc
**6-** wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
**7-** rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
**8-** yum install Judy
**9-** yum install MariaDB-Galera-server MariaDB*engine MariaDB-client rsync galera

It shows that oqgraph and other engines installed but when I check MariaDB engines with "SHOW ENGINES" oqgraph is not installed and when I try to install it with "INSTALL SONAME 'ha_oqgraph'" it gives me the error which I mentioned above.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Finally I didn't find any solution for installing oqgraph on Galera 10.0 Server

But it works fine with 10.1 version

Regards